# Importar a biblioteca do postgres na IDE intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lib

comecei a usar a IDE intellij idea a pouco tempo para desenvolver em java, anteriormente usava net beans e quando ia usar o banco de dados para minha aplicação era simples de importar a biblioteca do banco, como eu faço isso no intellij idea?

Comment: No caso a biblioteca do banco que você diz seria o Driver correto ? Caso sim, você precisa adicionar no classpath da sua aplicação, você utiliza alguma ferramenta de build tipo maven ?

Comment: Você se refere a adicionar manualmente uma lib (arquivo jar) ao projeto?

Comment: sim seria o driver,nesse projeto nao, mas tem o maven ,eu nunca usei, vi algo sobre fazer instalaçoes atraves dele, poderia me ajudar com detalhes maiores?

Comment: seria dicionar manualmente o driver a lib, no net beans vc ia no projeto em lib e importava o drive ja no intellij nao sei como se faz

Answer (score 1):

1. Clique no seu projeto e, a seguir, em: File > Project Structure...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Em Project Settings, vá em Modules > Dependencies > sinal de "+" > JARs or directories...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Selecione o arquivo jar e clique em OK, então OK novamente para confirmar.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Você pode ver o arquivo jar na pasta "External Libraries".
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vlw brother!!! era isso mesmo que eu queria

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta (clique na seta verde) para ajudar outros usuários que tenham a mesma dúvida que a sua.